# How to combine arrays inside multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have multidimensional array like this

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [batchCode] => 002-JR-11
                    [note] => TBY-457
                    [typeSex] => Male
                 )

             [1] => Array
                 (
                    [batchCode] => 002-JR-11
                    [note] => TBY-457
                    [typeSex] => Female
                 ) 

         )

      [1] => Array
          (
             [2] => Array
                 (
                    [batchCode] => 002-JR-12
                    [note] => AAJ-316
                    [typeSex] => Male
                 )

             [3] => Array
                 (
                    [batchCode] => 002-JR-12
                    [note] => AAJ-316
                    [typeSex] => Female
                 )

          )

  )
```

now i tried this code below:

```
 foreach($array as $k => $v){
      foreach($v as $s => $h){
          $temp_array[$h['batchCode']][$h['note']] = array(
              $s  => $h['typeSex'],
          );
      }
 }
```

and the result loops only the [1] => female and [3] => female. i want it to be like this.

```
  Array
  (
       [002-JR-11] => Array
                   (
                      [TBY-457] => Array
                          (
                             [0] => Male
                             [1] => Female
                          )

                   )

       [002-JR-12] => Array
                   (
                      [AAJ-316] => Array
                           (
                              [2] => Male
                              [3] => Female
                           )

                    )

   )
```

please help. this bother me thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 foreach($array as $k => $v){
  foreach($v as $s => $h){
      $temp_array[$h['batchCode']][$h['note']][] = $h['typeSex']

    }
 }
```

Comment: this code works! thanks i just add key of $v like this $temp_array[$h['batchCode']][$h['note']][$s] = $h['typeSex'] thanks!